# Set Heading Level With Props React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Just wondering if there is anyway to set heading levels by passing props down to the base component.

Example:

**Base Component**

```
class Heading extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <h{this.props.headinglevel} className={this.props.titleStyle}>
        {this.props.title}
    </h{this.props.headinglevel}>
  );
 }
}
export default Heading;
```

**Parent Component (Passing Props)**

```
class HomeHeader extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
      <Heading headinglevel="1" titleStyle="big-header" title="Hello World" />
  )
 }
}

export default HomeHeader;
```

When I try this I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yup! The way to make your tag a variable is as such:

```
render() {
    const Tag = 'h1';
    return <Tag>{/* some code here */}</Tag>;
}
```

Notice that `Tag` is capitalized. It is *required* you capitalize a tag variable so React understands it's not just a normal HTML element.

So in your case, you could do something like:

```
render() {
  const Tag = 'h' + this.props.headinglevel; // make sure this has a default value of "1" or w/e
  return (
    <Tag className={this.props.titleStyle}>
        {this.props.title}
    <Tag>
  );
}
```

---

(If you're being safe, you may want to add some check so `this.props.headinglevel` can only be 1-6.)

Comment: This is great, I figured it would be something close to this. New to react so leading the ropes as i go!